# Check if a packed resource exists in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Is there a way to check in code if a resource exists at an Uri such as:

```
"pack://application:,,,/MyResource.jpg"
```

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Just chop off the pack://application:,,,/ part of the string and do a File.Exists on the remaining part of the path.

Your snippet you posted is pointing to a file that lives in the root of the running application and is called MyResource.jpg.

Comment: Huh, since when does File.Exists look into the executing assembly's resources?

Comment: It doesn't, what Foovanadil is suggesting will only look in the current environment path. This answer is not correct.