# How to check if a WPF resource exists?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have an application, that reads a specific type of XML file. Those XML files can reference each other, e.g.:

```
<MyXml>
    <Reference Path="pack://application:,,,/MyOtherXML.xml"/>
    <!--More data-->
</MyXml>
```

This is mainly because they are quite long, and you don't want to repeat yourself with 180+ lines of XML.

However, I'm not sure how to check if the files exist if they are resources. I know that if they are normal files I can just use `File.Exists`, but I don't think you can do that for resources. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785387/check-if-a-packed-resource-exists-in-wpf), but the answer seems to be wrong. So how do you check if a resource exists on WPF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `GetManifestResourceStream` to get resources and read collection of keys from the dictionary something like this -

```
    public static string[] GetResourceNames()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
        {
            using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(entry => 
                         (string)entry.Key).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` get all the resource names and check on the results for the resource you want

```
var names = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
if(names.Contains(resourceNameTosearch))
{
    // exist 
}
```

Comment: That just gets me "MyProject.g.resources" and "MyProject.Properties.Resources.resources", not the other resources (there are 160+ others)